# Android Fragment and ViewModel issue

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel

I have created FragmentA and initialized the ViewModel inside onViewCreated(). I have attached the observer in the same method.

In FragmentA, I am making an API call and on the success of API call, I am replacing the FragmentA with FragmentB with addToBackStack.

Now the real problem starts when I press the back button in FragmentB, FragmentA in the back stack is called but immediately replaced by FragmentB again.

```
class FragmentA : Fragment(){
private var viewModel: TrackingViewModel?=null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initViewModel()
    attachObservers()
}

private fun initViewModel(){
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TrackingViewModel::class.java)
}

private fun attachObservers() {
    viewModel?.mResult?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        it?.let { resource ->
            parseResource(resource)
        }
    })
}

//Called this method on Button CLick in UI
private fun validate(data:String){
    viewModel?.coroutineSearch(data)
}

private fun parseResource(resource: Resource<GetsApiResponse>) {
    when (resource.status) {
        Status.SUCCESS -> {
            showLoading(false)
            //replaceFragmentWithBackStack is an Extension function
            replaceFragmentWithBackStack(FragmentB(), R.id.container)
        }
        Status.ERROR -> {
            showLoading(false)
            infoError(resource.responseCode)
        }
        Status.EXCEPTION -> {
            showLoading(false)
            infoException()
        }
        Status.LOADING -> {
            showLoading(true)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you use Navigation Component?

Comment: @A.R.B.N I am not using Navigation Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem at some point for everyone who works with `LiveData`. The problem here is caused by **intentional** `LiveData` behaviour: it returns you the value it stores (if any) as soon as you start observing it. `LiveData` was designed primarily to be used with view/data-binding solutions. As soon as a UI component is observing `LiveData` it should receive the value and display it appropriately. So the behaviour you get is intentional.

Many other developers, including me, had encountered this exact problem. I was able to solve it by using event wrapper recommended as a solution to this problem that I found in [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150). It is simple and easy to understand and works as described in the post.

Using this event wrapper your observer code will update to:

```
private fun attachObservers() {
    viewModel?.mResult?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        it?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { resource ->
            // Only proceed if the event has never been handled
            parseResource(resource)
        }
    })
}
```

If you are wondering why in the first place you immediately receive a result from this `LiveData` - it is because your view model was cached. When you are using activity as the view model store or store owner (`ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())`) your view model will live on until the activity you used is not destroyed. It means that even if you leave `FragmentA` by pressing back button to its previous fragment and then return back to `FragmentA` by creating a new instance you will get the same view model.

#### Event wrapper source code

```
/**
 * Used as a wrapper for data that is exposed via a LiveData that represents an event.
 */
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```